# Calculations for altimeter settings for variations in barometric pressure

Tags: altimeter, altitude

Pls help me with these 2 questions

An aircraft is standing on an airfield 220ft above sea level on a day when the barometric pressure at ground level is 1004 mb. If the pilot sets the altimeter to read 220ft on this day, what will it read if the barometric pressure drops to 992 mb.

An aircraft sets off from airfield A (126 ft above sea level) where the ground pressure is 1010 mb and flies to B (762 ft above sea level) where the ground pressure is 985 mb. If the pilot sets his altimeter (incorrectly) at 26ft at A, what will it read when it lands B?

Comment: An online E6B is at http://www.csgnetwork.com/e6bcalc.html.

Comment: I don't see how this question is likely to ever help any future visitors.

Comment: It looks like these questions come from a written test or a sample test? If so, I suggest that you explain what problem you have in answering them, so that someone can explain *how* to do the calculations rather than just giving you an answer that you still don't understand.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for the answer to sample knowledge test questions. While this site can be a great learning resource you won't learn much if we just give you the answers. Please reword your question to tell us what part of the related *concepts* you're unclear on and we'll reopen it so you can get answers that improve your understanding as opposed to just memorizing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: 550 ft.

Question 2: 660 ft.

(rounded to the next multiple of 10).

Atmospheric pressure drops by 1 mbar for every 8.5 m or 27.7 ft of altitude between 0 and 1000 ft, and the differences of your cases from the standard atmosphere are small, so I did not use corrections.